# How do I set the absolute path for an image?

Tags: 8, media, wysiwyg

I use image upload default ckeditor and IMCE module for drupal 8. But both of them return relative paths.

Output code actual relative path:

```
<img src="/sites/default/files/Images/image1.jpg">
```

Output code expected absolute path:

```
<img src="http://example.com/sites/default/files/Images/image1.jpg">
```

How to correct it?

Comment: Why would you not want relative pathing? As soon as you pull down the code/db to another environment or working locally, the images won't work (or load extremely slowly because you're pulling them across the network).

Answer (score 1):

IMCE has a checkbox setting to enable absolute paths in configuration page

Answer (score 1):

Step to set absolute path of image in ckeditor.

1. Firstly install and enable [image: IMCE] Module.
2. Go to the editor setting "admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html"
   In CKEditor plugin settings disable "Enable image uploads Disable to use   IMCE file browser." checkbox.

3.Go to IMCE setting page "admin/config/media/imce" and "Enable absolute URLs" checkbox in conman settings section. 
    [image]